# Mysql - store description and short_description or use SUBSTRING(description..)

Tags: mysql, optimization, substring

I have two fields in my DB, one is description (TEXT), the other is short_desc (VARCHAR-200).

When I display search results I obviously use the short_desc, and when someone clicks on the item they get the full description which can be several thousand characters in length.

Neither of these fields have indexes as I use Sphinx for searching.

My question is, do I need short_desc or is it wasting space when I could potentially use SUBSTRING() to retrive a shortened description?

If there isn't much overhead to SUBSTRING, it strikes me as being more flexible and less wasteful than storing short and long desriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't (i.e. it isn't wasting space) in general. In all MySQL 5 versions there are:

- MySQL never uses indexes with functions in conditions (something like `WHERE SUBSTR(X, 1, 2)=Y`)
- You can build an index on VARCHAR column. I.e. if you will use short text - you'll be certain that you can use indexing by it and that index will be used. On `TEXT` column building an index is possible [only with certain length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html).

So if you have many `SELECT` queries - it's a good idea to have short descriptions (besides written above, `TEXT` fields are [stored separately](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), so accessing them could cause the worst issue - disk operations). In this case you'll be able to create and use index with avoiding unnecessary disk reading operations.

Comment: If we forget indexing because I never will use indexes on either of those columns....should `SELECT short_desc FROM table` be significantly faster than `SELECT SUBSTR(description,1,120) FROM table`? Because I'm not seeing any real difference on single queries?

Comment: In general, yes - using `VARCHAR` will be faster - since `TEXT` fields stored separately on disk in MySQL (so, to do `SUBSTR` you will need to read field first, i.e. probably access to disk space). And if you're going to do some `SELECT` queries - better to build correct indexes.

Answer (score 1):

From a database perspective, the overhead of keeping an additional 200 characters is rather minimal, if your record length is already several kbytes.

My concern would be tying whims of the user interface into the underlying database structure.  Why would the short description be exactly 200 characters?  What about breaking a word in the middle of the word?  Or a number in the middle of a number?  Wouldn't you prefer to break on a punctuation boundary?

The point here is that there is no "right" answer.  If you have a field for short description, and it is in the database, then be prepared that someone may want to modify it to make it prettier.  If your user interface just wants to take the first 200 characters, then be prepared for a new version that wants 100.  Or 250.

I don't think database performance should be the key issue here.  The additional overhead for the substring would be potentially one more page read for the longer string.  That is probably not noticeable for a user-facing application.

Comment: Well at the moment the short_description is a version of description under 200 characters but with the elipses inserted at an appropriate place.

The problem I've had in the past (as you rightly point) is that changes to the website have warranted longer 'short description' strings, and as a result the entire database of several million records has needed to be re-generated with new, longer, short_description's.